# webpack-dev-server doesn't not reloading after editing typescript class twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, pixi.js

I'm using pixiJS with webpack and typescript. When I run dev server on `webpack-dev-server --mode development`, it works preatty well. So, I change one of my classes called Water.ts and the hot reload works good on the first time. But when I change the file again, the webpage reload but doesn't change the file. It's seen like webpack doesn't compile the .ts file, except for the first time.

Here is [the little project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1freA09oAYgwDuAV1ES7qth2zjmIM0rzK/view?usp=sharing).

For exemple: I change the line 18 on Water.ts to `this.anim.scale.set(6);` from `this.anim.scale.set(4);`. It's work. But when I change that to `this.anim.scale.set(6);` or whatever in the file, it's stoped working.

Has anyone had this problem too?

Comment: Are you accessing the dev server as `localhost`? Do you see any network errors in the development console?

Comment: yes, i do. No, there is no error